# What iOS devices have SQLite? Will all new devices in the coming years support SQLite?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have looked into SQLite with iOS development, and I found that the iPhone 6, and iPhone 7 will support SQLite version 3.7.13. I find it hard to believe that these are the ONLY ones that support it. Are there any iPads that also support it, and other iPhones like iPhone 6 Plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has been supplied with iOS since iOS 2.0. It is available for any iOS device. There is no reason to think that will stop.

But even if Apple stopped supplying it, you could still use it. It's just a third party library you can include in your app.

Its support is based on being part of your app, not any specific device or version of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes IPhone and iPad support sqlite It is part of Core Services in ios architecture layers